# How to disable validators using the XSP.partialRefreshPost method?

Tags: javascript, xpages

I am using XSP.partialRefreshPost to trigger a partial refresh from client side Javascript. I would like to be able to do the partial refresh without triggering the validators (which is just a simple attribute on an ordinary input control).

I have found several references to an "options" argument that you can use in conjuntion with XSP.partialRefreshPost (including the ability to control validation). However, I have not found any places that describes the syntax/option names???

Anyone knows how to do this?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I have added a couple of examples of what I have tried - to clarify the issue. I have had my nose in the XPages Portable Command Guide as well.

First, using the "immediate" paramter:

```
$(".selectCtrl").on("change", function(e){XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:repeatCtrl}", {immediate: true})})
```

Then, using the "valmode" paramter:

```
$(".selectCtrl").on("change", function(e){XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:repeatCtrl}", {params: {'valmode': 0}})})
```

The latter with variations of quotes around "valmode" and "0".

None of these worked... (i.e. the refresh kicks in - but is stopped by the validator failing). I hope that I am just getting the wrong syntax here - but haven't been able to find any working examples - yet ;-)

Comment: hmm - same here: none of your 2 options will be working or me. While {params: {"valmode": 0}} can't be correct in the first place, if I'm getting Sven right it should be just {valmode: 0} without the params part (or maybe {valmode: '0'}..?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a *PhaseListener* which disables the validation if required:

```
package ch.hasselba.demo;

import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;
import com.ibm.xsp.context.ExternalContextEx;
import com.ibm.xsp.context.FacesContextExImpl;

public class DisableValidationPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent arg0) {}

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent arg0) {
        FacesContextExImpl fc  = (FacesContextExImpl) arg0.getFacesContext();
        ExternalContextEx ec = (ExternalContextEx) fc.getExternalContext();

        // check for the "disableValidation" parameter & disable validation
        // if required
        if( ec.getRequestParameterMap().containsKey("disableValidation") )
            fc.setDisableValidators(true);
    }

    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.PROCESS_VALIDATIONS;
    }

}
```

You just have to add a parameter to your PartialRefresh, and the validation is disabled:

```
XSP.partialRefreshPost('#{id:refreshMe}', {'params': {'disableValidation':true}} );
```

Comment: ... and following my comment to your other answer - then I suppose I WILL have to create a home-grown solution. And in that case I admit I prefer the phase listener approach as more "clean" ;-)

Comment: For everybody reading this answer, please note that the method "setDisableValidators" is not defined on the ordinary FacesContext but in FacesContextExImpl. I don't know if there are any implications on this...?

Comment: The *FacesContextExImpl* is the extended *FacesContext* object used in XPages by the IBM.

Comment: It works!!! I only had to get the code where I add the event listeners inside of the panel that I refresh - probably obvious to everone (just took me a moment to figure out). Thanks for the solution!!

Comment: Just a note that for this to work you need to reference the Java Class in the faces-config.xml:   <lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>ch.hasselba.demo.DisableValidationPhaseListener</phase-listener>
  </lifecycle>

Comment: Hey Sven, unfortunately this phaselistener doesn´t work when I use XSP.partialRefreshGet. Which Phase do I have to check if I need to use Get?

Comment: Hmm, Validation is running when processing a GET request? This should not happen during the JSF lifecycle. Maybe you should create a question here and add some code for a better understanding!?

Answer (score 2):

The parameter *valmode* sets the validation mode and has the following options:

0 for no validation

1 for execution of converters only

2 for execution of converters & validators

For older versions (<8.5.2) it is just true or false.

**EDIT:**
This works for ClientSide Validation only.

Comment: great info. Is there a reference for that and (hopefully) for other XSP methods as well?

Comment: Sven, thanks for your comments. I have edited my question to show the variations I have tried - perhaps I am just not getting the syntax right?

Comment: @Lothar: No, there is no reference.

Comment: Ahhh.... so these options only apply to _client side_ validation... That explains it - but sort of break the connection to the event properties on a control...

Answer (score 0):

Never tried that before, but according to my copy of the Xpages Portable Command Guide we can send variuous kinds of POST request parameters (I grew to like that book a lot recently...). So I gave it a quick shot and it seems to work on my side. Here's the setup:

- Xpage with 2 buttons plus a panel (id = "fieldContainer").
- Inside the panel sits a simple inputText control with an active required validator.
- A button

The button calls the following CSJS script:

```
var opt={disableVal":"true"}; //pass param value as text
XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:fieldContainer}", {params: opt});
```

To my inputText I add the following SSJS code under "All Properties > data > disableValidators":

```
if(!params.isEmpty()){
  if(param.get("disableVal")==="true"){true}
}
```

To verify that the refresh indeed took place I added a computedField control into the same panel bound to a SSJS code showing me the current data/time value:

```
@Now()
```

Hope this helps

EDIT:
the book also mentions an option to pass an immediate parameter, but that most probably would not only suppress validation but also submission and conversion of submitted values (I didn't try that one, but nevertheless here's the syntax as described therein):

```
XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:idOfControl}", {immediate: true});
```

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correct what you do is implement your "own hack" - which is what I would ideally want to avoid. It seems that the {immediate: true} should do the same as (valmode:0} that should disable converters as well as validators. I just can't get it to work. I have also tried the {immediate: true} - it refreshes alright - but stops on the validators....