# Calling XSP.partialRefreshPost on tokeninput field

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to implement the JQuery tokeninput plugin to an XPages app using the examples from Mark Rodens site.  I've been going back and forth on a couple of problems which I can't seem to get over.

1) Validation on the inputText2 field is always called regardless of the **immediate** parameter to the XSP.partialRefreshPost call
2) The value selected is not binding the source document (in this case document1.AppName).

Here's my code (forgive the mess)

```
<xp:panel id="panel1">
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{document1.AppName}">
    </xp:inputText>
    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock3">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#[id$=inputText1]").tokenInput([{      
            "first_name": "Arthur",
            "last_name": "Godfrey",
            "email": "arthur_godfrey@nccu.edu",
            "url": "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_2_normal.png"
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Adam",
            "last_name": "Johnson",
            "email": "wravo@yahoo.com",
            "url": "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_2_normal.png"
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Jeff",
            "last_name": "Johnson",
            "email": "bballnine@hotmail.com",
            "url": "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_2_normal.png"
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Adriana",
            "last_name": "Jameson",
            "email": "adriana.jameson@gmail.com",
            "url": "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_2_normal.png"
        }
      ], {
         tokenLimit: 1,
          propertyToSearch: "first_name",
        onAdd: function (item) {
                alert(item.first_name);
                var idp = "#{id:panel1}";
                document.getElementById("#{id:inputText1}").value = item.first_name
                XSP.partialRefreshPost(idp, {immediate:true});
            },
    });
    });
    ]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
getComponent=<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("inputText1").getValue()}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
<xp:br></xp:br>
    document1.AppName=
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2" value="#{document1.AppName}">
</xp:text>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:inputText id="inputText2" required="true">
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateRequired message="Please enter a value"></xp:validateRequired>
    </xp:this.validators></xp:inputText>
<xp:message id="message1" for="inputText2"></xp:message></xp:panel>
```

The only way I can even get a value to stick anywhere is to set the field directly using the value of the item selected in the onAdd event.  This is where I call XSP.partialRefreshPost in order to refresh the panel and hopefully display the bound value in the computed text field.

Any ideas as to what may be missing? I'm sure it's something stupid!

Comment: It does not seem possible to add the immediate property to partialRefreshPost(). See this question and answer for a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21912966/785061

Comment: Aidan - without context I am not sure why you are refreshing the fields. Is the problem that the tokenInput'ized field is not bound to the document, or is partialRefresh causing you pain?

Comment: Mark, basically this will fit into an existing project where after selecting from the tokeninput field (where I am presently using standard typeaheads) a panel is updated showing other data based on the selected value.  I was hoping to implement tokeninput as a 'nicer' way of doing the typeahead.  The problem is that the field doesn't seem to be bound to the document (the two computed text fields show the bound value and the value from the field).  The other problem is that I want to avoid validation on the refresh.  I'm off to look at the link that Per has provided.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Aidan - I suggest making a basic example - one field which works for you and then work that into your application. Start simple rather than trying to implement into existing code.