# xpages 2 partial refreshes from a required field

Tags: xpages

I have an inputText which is a required field on my Document.

```xpages
<xp:inputText value="#{Cdoc.txt_NumeCompanie}" id="txt_NumeCompanie"
                        required="true" defaultValue="#{javascript:param.value}">
        <xp:this.validators>
                <xp:validateRequired message="Numele companiei este obligatoriu." loaded="true">
                </xp:validateRequired>
        </xp:this.validators>
        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="false" disableValidators="true">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[   XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:scrollDiv}", {
                        onComplete: function() {
                            XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:pers}");
                        }
                    });
                ]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:inputText>
```

I also checked the `Process data without validation` ( from the Server tab ... ).  But still no refresh is taking place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not include the required second parameter on your second partialRefreshPost. Try this:

```
XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:scrollDiv}", {
    onComplete: function() {
        XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:pers}", {});
    }
});
```

**Update:** you can use the onComplete event of the eventHandler to run your 2nd partial refresh. So use the traditional partial refresh of the first component and then run your 2nd partial refresh through the onComplete event:

```
<xp:inputText value="#{Cdoc.txt_NumeCompanie}" id="txt_NumeCompanie" required="true" defaultValue="#{javascript:param.value}">
    <xp:this.validators>
            <xp:validateRequired message="Numele companiei este obligatoriu." loaded="true">
            </xp:validateRequired>
    </xp:this.validators>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="scrollDiv">
        <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:pers}", {});]]></xp:this.onComplete>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:inputText>
```

Comment: No, i tried this: <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
  refreshMode="norefresh" disableValidators="true">
  <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:scrollDiv}", {});]]></xp:this.script>
 </xp:eventHandler>

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how you can use the onComplete eventHandler event

Comment: I;ve just checked also the "Process data without validation". It works.

Answer (score 3):

By setting submit="false", you're preventing any server-side processing from being triggered by the eventHandler itself. That means disableValidators="true" is irrelevant, because the XPages lifecycle is not being processed from the eventHandler.

Instead the refresh is being generated from the client-side code, the XSP.partialRefreshPost. That doesn't have an option to disable validation, as covered here [How to disable validators using the XSP.partialRefreshPost method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912966/how-to-disable-validators-using-the-xsp-partialrefreshpost-method). disableValidators="true" doesn't and cannot influence the processing of the partialRefreshPost. So chances are your validation is still running. To confirm that, add an errors panel into the initial refresh area.

partialRefreshGet may work, I'm not sure.

My usual approach in these scenarios is to refresh a single area that comprises both areas you wish to refresh. Then set submit="true" and disableValidators="true". But bear in mind that even if validation is disabled, data conversion is still checked so if you enter a text value in a number field, the partial refresh would still fail.

Comment: I really can't use a single area ( panel ) which contains the 2 areas ( panels ), so I must refresh the 2 panels, not being contained by a single one. I tried with partialRefreshGet, but it doesn't work.

Comment: partialRefreshGet only pulls from the server, it doesn't post. So the server doesn't know about any changes the user has made on the web page. A standard partial refresh with a partialRefreshGet in the onComplete may work. If you want to just use CSJS, you need to identify how to perform a partialRefreshPost without triggering validation. *IF* validation is triggering and causing it to fail, but there's no way for me to be able to tell you that's occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first thing to do is open your toolbox and look at the network traffic. This will help you to understand what is going on. You can use FireBug in FireFox or Developer tools in Google Chrome.

What network traffic occurs for the above snippet?

***Edit:***

Still waiting to hear what network traffic is generated...

But just looking at your code... - try set submit="true". I had a look at some of the code I have, and I am not sure that the extra empty param is required :-)

Could you explain what you are trying to obtain?

***Edit***

Ok, I see what you want. I had a quick view in some code. I am not doing exactly the same that you are. However, when I nest the partial refreshes I typically do it this way:

```
<xp:button id="button1"
    styleClass="btn btn-danger btn-lg#{FishingTripEdit.typeInput eq '1' ? ' inActive' : ''}">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="inputTypeSelected" disableValidators="true">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:executeScript>
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:MyBean.setData('0')}]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:executeScript>
        </xp:this.action>
        <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:buttonTopHolder}")]]></xp:this.onComplete>
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[return document.getElementById("#{id:triggerAsk}").value!=='1' ? true : confirm("Sure?")]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

So for the "first" refresh I use the builtin markup - and onComplete I add the second as plain JavaScript. I know this is an example with a partialRefreshGet (which I prefer to use if at all possible due to less overhead). But perhaps it can give you an idea....

Comment: If I set submit="true", it will do a full update by the server. I do not want a full update on page, just 2 partial refreshes for 2 panels. Depending on the above described inputText value, I'm trying to hide/show some elements situated on the 2 panels.

Comment: Try with just one partialRefreshPost and see if that works/generates an ajax request.

Comment: submit="true" does not do a full update of the page, refreshMode="full" controls that. submit="true" means "post the content to the server after CSJS has run". Without submit="true", an eventHandler doesn't do any kind of refresh, partial or otherwise. It just runs CSJS.

Comment: refreshMode="complete", not refreshMode="full"

Comment: Thanks Paul. That was what I thought - but was pulled away from this discussion. It needs to send data back to the server to calculate the show/hide properties. Florin, if you want to minimize the amount of data sent, you should take a look at an excellent article by Sven Hasselbach: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1383 - and he also uses the dev.tools in the browser to see what happens.... - just like I asked you to in the first place. I am sure you would have found nothing was sent :-)