# HowTo update Backing Bean before partial refresh

Tags: java, xml, xpages

I want to refresh a XPages' control, that displays data based on input of a ListBox. I use a `Backing Bean` that holds the data. The `Backing Bean` is connected by `EL Value Binding`.
For a Computed Text Control, the Backing Bean returns the first selected value of the `listData` property.

```
public class BackingBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List listData;
    private String displayData;

    public BackingBean() {}

    public List getListData() {
        System.out.println("getListData()");
        return listData;
    }

    public void setListData(List listData) {
        System.out.println("setListData()");
        this.listData = listData;
    }


    public String getDisplayData() {
        System.out.println("getDisplayData()");

        if(listData != null && listData.size() > 0) {
            return (String) listData.get(0);    
        } 

        return "NO LIST DATA";
    }

}
```

Here is my XPage code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">   

    <xp:div id="refreshMe">
        <xp:listBox id="listBox1">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{backingBean.listData}]]></xp:this.value>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Value 1"></xp:selectItem>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Value 2"></xp:selectItem>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="refreshMe">
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:listBox>

    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{backingBean.displayData}"></xp:text>
</xp:div>

</xp:view>
```

The problem is, on partial refresh, the data will be sent to the server, but the setListData setter is never called. 
The computed text only shows "NO LIST DATA".

```
view:_id1:listBox1:Value 1 // <-- selected option is sent to the server
$$viewid:!e9x9cl6xse!
$$xspsubmitid:view:_id1:_id298
$$xspexecid:
$$xspsubmitvalue:
$$xspsubmitscroll:0|0
view:_id1:view:_id1
```

How can I do a partial refresh off a control, whose value relies on value bound data of another control?

Answer (score 1):

#### Found cause and solution!

When I set `disableValidators` to `true` the `setListData` setter will be called and the Backing Bean gets updated.

```
<xp:listBox id="listBox1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{controller.listData}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Value 1"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Value 2"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="refreshMe" disableValidators="true"></xp:eventHandler>
</xp:listBox>
```

To be honest, I also want to update data by using `XSP.partialRefreshPost`. When I try this, I'm not able to disable validation out of the box.
But Sven Hasselbach posted a solution for this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21931796/4735030
(In short: Implement a PhaseListener that disables Validation on demand.)

The event handler, that uses `XSP.partialRefreshPost` looks like this:

```
<xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[   
        XSP.partialRefreshPost(#{id:refreshMe}', {'params': {'disableValidation':true}});
    ]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

Comment: Please always confirm if code pasted in a question is just part of what's on an XPage. There were no required fields, so although validation is typically the most common cause of updates not running, I didn't mention that. Also, always ensure there is an errors panel in a refreshed area. Otherwise there is no way for you or the users to see if a validation *or data conversion* error has occurred.

Comment: The code is all I've used. There are no required fields nor any validators or converters.

Comment: But disableValidators works, so there is a validation error occurring. I would encourage you to add a Display Errors control to understand what error is occurring. If it's a conversion error to List, that would still be thrown even with disableValidators set to true. But something's throwing an error. A PhaseListener logging out a message for before/after each phase will also confirm if it's skipping out after Process Validation phase, which also confirms SSJS won't run.

Comment: I add the errors display control, but no message appears. I guess the updating issue is related to the listbox control: If I add a onclick button, that does the partial refresh based on the value of a textinput control, the backing bean gets updated (partial execution mode enabled for the textinput). This does not happen, if I the button's execId points to the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `setListData(String listData)` method as well. "1" is not a List, so I wouldn't expect it to call your current method. I'm also not sure whether an `xp:listBox` maps to a List or a Vector. I would expect it to map to a Vector.

Comment: Good idea and I added this method - but it's not called at all. Also if there is no setter method that consumes a List Object, it gets rendered as readonly - as if there is no setter for this property.