# After validation error document.setValue("value") doesn´t work anymore

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, ssjs

I have a document datasource on my Xpage to which I bound fields. Some are required. When I save the datasource and have validation errors the code below doesn´t work anymore on a partial refresh.

```
document.setValue("key","value");
```

This is my partial refresh call:

```
XSP.partialRefreshGet('#{id:refreshContactInfos}', {params: { 'reference': this.value, 'disableValidation':true}});
```

Within the div with id="refreshContactInfos" I have an hidden field which should set values of fields to populate them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the XSP.partialRefresh**Get** to XSP.partialRefresh**Post** worked for me.

```
XSP.partialRefreshPost('#{id:refreshContactInfos}', {params: { 'reference': this.value, 'disableValidation':true}});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in JSF lifecycle. I think your partial refresh wont update data because of validation errors (anywhere).

Look here to disable validation in XSP call (a bit hacky way).
[How to disable validators using the XSP.partialRefreshPost method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912966/how-to-disable-validators-using-the-xsp-partialrefreshpost-method)

Another solution is to make ordinary event with disabled validation (invisible button) and invoking that one, instead of XSP object call.