# prevent validation while running XSP.partialRefreshPost

Tags: xpages, jquery-select2

In an xpage I have two select2 lists. The choice in the first select box directs the options in the second select box.

The lists are defines via List Box controls.

In order to have select2 applied to them I have a scriptblock

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        x$("#{id:list1}").select2();
    }
)
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        x$("#{id:list2}").select2();
    }
)
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        x$("#{id:list1}").on("change", function(e) {
            XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:pnlList2}"
})
```

pnlList2 contains the second list box.

The problem is that the validation for the second list is triggered when the first list box changes in value.

I tried to apply as parameters:

```
'params': {
    'disableVal':'true'
}
```

but that does not work as desired.

anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: I've used this method in the past : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912966/how-to-disable-validators-using-the-xsp-partialrefreshpost-method/21931796

Comment: thanks Mark. that code works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to go about it, but I prefer the most performing one, that is partial execution. Partial execution should be mandatory as a best practice.

What happens with your code is that you refresh a portion of your page while validating the whole of it. By doing this the second select gets caught without value.

I would define the `onchange` param for the combobox - not the event handler - so that the select2 will automatically pick up the event without declaring it through JavaScript later on as you do.

Just use:

```
<xp:combobox onchange=“XSP.partialRefreshPost('#{id:select2Id}', { execId: '#{id:select1Id}' }”
```

As I said select2 will see the onchange declared in this way and honor it. When it will fire only the combobox1 will be evaluated, thus automatically skipping any other validation on the page because not included. At this point the second select will not complain and be refreshed.

An additional word of advice is to reinitialize the second combobox with select2 because the partial refresh will destroy it. Better to expand the partial refresh area to include both the combobox and the scriptBlock specific for the second select.